# IDA: Is bank switching supported (for Z80 disassembly)?

Tags: ida

First of all, I'm pretty new to IDA and don't understand all its features just yet.

I'd like to inspect the ROM of a Sega Master System game. The console is based on the Z80 microprocessor, with 8K of RAM (C000-DFFFh, shadowed at E000-FFFFh). Since the Z80 can only address 64K of memory and most games are larger than that (128K, 256K, and 512K are used), the console implements a bank switching mechanism with 16K chunks to make all of the memory available. The usual way this is accomplished is by keeping the first 32K (or two banks) permanently resident (0000-7FFFh) and bank switch the rest (all addressed 8000-BFFFh) by writing the bank number to a pseudo-register at FFFFh in RAM.

Now, is there a way to make IDA understand this scheme? For now, I can load all of the ROM in segments (one segment per bank) but doing it this way, jumps/calls after a bank switch are pointing to the wrong location because it doesn't know which one is currently selected.